# Triggering a list workflow on every 10th item added to a list

Tags: 2007, list, workflow

SharePoint 2007 Standard License

An internal customer has requested a basic document control facility, which has been built.  Rather than receiving alerts on each item and change, they've asked if it's possible to reeive an alert for every 10th item that's been created in the list.

Thus my questions for the community are to ask if this is possible and if so, what approach would you take?

Tools at my disposal are SharePoint Designer and client side changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what they want is an every day update instead? 2007 alerts come with that functionality built in.

Other options include @Paul Leigh 's approach as a calculated column, creating a view, and setting up the alert that way. That is...

=MOD([ID],10)
...and view only displays items if the Calculated Column is equal to 1... and alert triggers every time an item is present in that view.

Comment: The everyday summary I was aware of but didn't see a way to use it.  I didn't think about the modulo approach either.  I'll give this a go and will advise how it works oit.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no clean way to do this but you can achieve what you want by creating another List in which you'll store the count of items inserted in your other list. Then, when this count is equal to 10, you can send your email notification.

So, to recap, you need:

- List 1 - the list where you currently store documents.
- List 2 - counter list. Create just one column named "Counter" of type number.
  Insert one row in List 2 and set Counter = 0.

Attach a workflow to List#1 and set it to start automatically upon item creation.
Add an action to update an item in a list (List#2 in this case) and increment the value of Counter column by one.

Attach a workflow to List#2 and set it to start automatically when an item is changed.
Add a check to see if Counter equals 10, then reset it to 0 and send your email alert.

A dirty trick but should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have SP2007 to hand (or SPD for that matter) so I can't test this but in psuedo code in a workflow, try:

declare a variable (ModNumTen) as a Number
declare a variable (ModIntTen) as an Integer

Set ModNumTen as the [Document ID] MOD 10. 
Set ModIntTen as the [Document ID] MOD 10

if(ModNumTen == ModIntTen) ....

If there are equal, you have an ID that is the 10th logical item in the list, so send the email.